# What is a simply connected space and a multiply connected space?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I was reading the book *Hyperspace* by Michio Kaku when I read about simply connected space and multiply connected space. I just tried searching the answer using Wikipedia but I wasn't able to understand the definition.

Comment: Did you try [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space)?

Comment: yes but i am not able to understand the definition exactly

Comment: I suggest you to (1) be more specific about what do you not understanding, and (2) provide a little bit about your math background.

Comment: The "Informal Discussion" on Wikipedia is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A space is [simply connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) if any two points in the space can be joined by a continuous path lying in the space, and every continuous loop in the space can be continuously contracted to a point.

For example, a circle fails to be simply connected, whereas a sphere is simply connected. Roughly speaking, a space is simply connected if there are no "tunnels" or "punctures" in it.